I have the "Tx TextControl.NET for windows form 20.0 Express" Issue when loading the control
Takes too long when loading the control and the information but it is weird it just happens for one session and it happens when the function starts textcontrol.load(data, stringtype), anyone please knows what happens or what could be the problem?
I just search information about library but couldnt find

I suggest that you file the issue to the makers of this control.

Try https://www.textcontrol.com/

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
